# Disable checkbox through Status javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble with disabling the checkbox based on their status. On my current data when the field status is equal to `Paid` the checkbox should be disabled. It would be great if anybody could figure out where I am going wrong. thank you so much in advance, This is what it looks like.

[image]

```js
const toggle = (source) => {
  const checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('product_id[]');
  checkboxes.forEach(cb => {
    cb.checked = source.checked;
  });
  compute();
}

const compute = () => {
  const checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('product_id[]');
  let total = 0;
  let checked = 0;
  checkboxes.forEach(cb => {
    if (cb.checked) {
      checked++;
      const amountElt = cb.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("amount")[0];
      total += parseInt(amountElt.innerText, 10);
    }
  });
  document.getElementById("total_checked").innerText = checked;
  document.getElementById("total_amount").innerText = total;


  if (checked === 0) {
    document.getElementById("selectall").checked = false;
  } else if (checked === checkboxes.length) {
    document.getElementById("selectall").checked = true;
  }
}

document.getElementsByName('product_id[]').forEach(cb => {
  cb.addEventListener('change', compute);
});
```

```html
  Checked <p id="total_checked"></p>
  Amount <p id="total_amount"></p>
  <table class="table" name="table" id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th><input id="selectall" type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /></th>
        <th>Sample</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>trtrtr</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]"></td>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Paid</td>
        <td class="amount">5200</td>
        <td>someval</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]"></td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Unpaid</td>
        <td class="amount">8000</td>
        <td>someval</td>
      </tr>

       <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]"></td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Unpaid</td>
        <td class="amount">8000</td>
        <td>someval</td>
       <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]"></td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Paid</td>
        <td class="amount">8000</td>
        <td>someval</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]"></td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>Unpaid</td>
        <td class="amount">8000</td>
        <td>someval</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, if i'm not wrong understanding your code

```
 if (checked === 0) {
    // unpaid condition
    document.getElementById("selectall").checked = false;
  } else if (checked === checkboxes.length) {
    // paid condition
    document.getElementById("selectall").checked = true;
    document.getElementById("selectall").disabled= true;
  }
```

Update: I don't answer via code but the clue is, You should add name="product_paid[]" attribute inside PAID and UNPAID tr tag
everytime the UI updates, you should call a function to check if this checkbox should be disabled or not

Update 2 let me try the code snippets I think this is what you intended

```js
const toggle = (source) => {
  const checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('product_id[]');
  checkboxes.forEach((cb, idx) => {
    
    const paidElement = document.getElementsByName("product_paid[]")[idx];
    const paidText = paidElement.innerText
    if(paidText !== 'Paid'){
     cb.checked = source.checked;
    }
  });
  compute();
}

const compute = () => {
  const checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('product_id[]');
  let total = 0;
  let checked = 0;
  checkboxes.forEach((cb, idx) => {
    if (cb.checked) {
      checked++;
      const amountElt = cb.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("amount")[0];
      total += parseInt(amountElt.innerText, 10);
    }

    const paidElement = document.getElementsByName("product_paid[]")[idx];
    const paidText = paidElement.innerText
    if(paidText === 'Paid'){
     cb.disabled = true
    }
  });
  document.getElementById("total_checked").innerText = checked;
  document.getElementById("total_amount").innerText = total;


  if (checked === 0) {
    document.getElementById("selectall").checked = false;
  } else if (checked === checkboxes.length) {
    document.getElementById("selectall").checked = true;
  }
}

document.getElementsByName('product_id[]').forEach(cb => {
  cb.addEventListener('change', compute);
});
compute()
```

```html
  Checked <p id="total_checked"></p>
  Amount <p id="total_amount"></p>
  <table class="table" name="table" id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th><input id="selectall" type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /></th>
        <th>Sample</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>trtrtr</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]"></td>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td name="product_paid[]">Paid</td>
        <td class="amount">5200</td>
        <td>someval</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]"></td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td name="product_paid[]">Unpaid</td>
        <td class="amount">8000</td>
        <td>someval</td>
      </tr>

       <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]"></td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td name="product_paid[]">Unpaid</td>
        <td class="amount">8000</td>
        <td>someval</td>
       <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]"></td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td name="product_paid[]">Paid</td>
        <td class="amount">8000</td>
        <td>someval</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]"></td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td name="product_paid[]">Unpaid</td>
        <td class="amount">8000</td>
        <td>someval</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it doesn't work, the condition  should be equal to "Paid"  inorder to disable the checkbox